# system won't poweroff, restarts with :"Synchronizing SCSI cache"

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown

Running Debian testing, after a system upgrade a while back my machine started to refuse to power down. It hangs with:

```
Synchronizing SCSI cache
```

Waits a few seconds, and then reboots itself.  It doesn't matter which command I use (poweroff, halt, shutdown ..).  I have a backup install that does not have the problem, and that shares the same kernel.  Strangely about one time in three or four, it will poweroff fine.

FWIW, `hdparm -F /dev/sda` shows this:

```
/dev/sda:
HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(flushcache) failed: Input/output error
```

... so that looks suspicious, however the drive works fine. I've tried
several `hdparm` commands to try to make the disk happy, but nothing 
changes.

This seems to be a systemd issue. I think the disk is involved.  FWIW, I noticed these differences in /var/log/syslog: (trimmed down to show only the interesting parts):

BAD:

Stopping Session 1 of user root.
Stopped Session 1 of user root.
Stopping system-ifup.slice.
Removed slice system-ifup.slice.
Stopping Sound Card.
Stopped target Sound Card.
Stopping system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Stopping Console Manager...
Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Stopping Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
Stopping Graphical Interface.
Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Stopping Multi-User System.
Stopped target Multi-User System.
Stopping System Logging Service...

GOOD:

Stopping Session 1 of user root.
Stopped Session 1 of user root.
Stopping system-ifup.slice.
Removed slice system-ifup.slice.
Stopping Sound Card.
Stopped target Sound Card.
Stopping system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
Stopping Disk Manager...
Stopping Console Manager...
Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
Stopping Default.
Stopped target Default.
Stopping Basic System.
Stopped target Basic System.
Stopping Paths.
Stopped target Paths.
Stopping Timers.
Stopped target Timers.
Stopping Sockets.
Stopped target Sockets.
Starting Shutdown.
Reached target Shutdown.
Starting Exit the Session...

I wish I could capture all the messages that show on screen, there's many more than show up in syslog.

Comment: what happens when you run sync manually? i would advise to take full backup -- then run some dig diagnostics is it a RAID? is it possible that the cache card on the array controller is having an issue ?

Comment: Nope, no RAID, just a simple SATA disk. 'sync' manually didn't seem to have any effect. Worked fine until recently and (as I said, still fine with Debian backup). What diagnostics? There's nothing obvious in the shutdown dialogue.